# InvalidArchiveError when installing GNURadio on Windows 10 from command line. Seems to be issue with libarchive or codec2

Tags: python-3.x, windows, conda, gnuradio, libarchive

```
InvalidArchiveError("Error with archive C:\\Users\\RDCRLCLW\\Miniconda3\\pkgs\\codec2-0.9.2-h301d43c_1.tar.bz2.  You probably need to delete and re-download or re-create this file.  Message from libarchive was:\n\nCan't create '\\\\?\\C:\\Users\\RDCRLCLW\\Miniconda3\\pkgs\\codec2-0.9.2-h301d43c_1\\Library\\bin\\fdmdv_get_test_bits.exe'")
```

This occurs when installing GNURadio, either the most recent or 3.8.2 with conda version 4.10.0

I am trying to install via conda-forge and have tried it several different ways:

- as a general user
- as admin
- reinstalled miniconda
- tried installing codec2 on its own
- `conda clean -a`

Been wrestling with this all day and not sure how to get beyond this step... I've seen some similar InvalidArchiveError posts but none quite the same and posted solutions do not seem to work for this instance. any tips greatly appreciated!

EDIT:

Tried earlier versions of libarchive, codec2, and conda with no dice. I've read this can also happen when not enough space is on the hard drive but I have more than enough. Need this package installed somehow so would appreciate hearing from anyone who's figured it out!

Answer (score 0):

Don't update CONDA to 4.10.0, the new version is unstable

Comment: Had high hopes but no dice, tried conda 4.9.2 and 4.9.1

Wondering if it has something to do with libarchive, may try playing with that next